# Python - Check windows firewall status

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is there any python command or module can check Windows firewall status ?
If it could work in linux, please let me know too.

Thanks so much,
Quang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following may help you in same.

```
subprocess.check_call('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles')
```

Comment: May i ask way to check Windows Updates Status too ?
Thanks RavinderSingh13,

Comment: @QuangLe, as per rules, I would request you to open a new thread for this question.

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh13,

Comment: I have a question about your solution. I can't make it become value of a variable.  
i try all the way that i know but it doesn't work.

Comment: @QuangLe, since I don't have windows system with me so can't test it, try this URL solution and let us know if this helps. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output